# Knockout model holder doesn't get updated automatilcally

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout MVVM model for my application

```
self.advanceDetails = 
    {

        hasUserInPutEvoucherTotalLimit: self.evoucherTotalLimit,
        isEvoucherMaxLimit: self.noMaxUseLimit,
        maxUseLimit: self.noMaxUseLimit() ? -1 : self.evoucherMaxLimit,
        hasUserInPutEvoucherMaxLimit: self.evoucherMaxLimit,
        expiredDaysToShow: self.expiryDays,
        registerPromoWaitTime: self.waitTimeDays
    };
```

here

```
     maxUseLimit: self.noMaxUseLimit() ? -1 : self.evoucherMaxLimit
```

doesn't get changed if self.noMaxUseLimit gets changed. i mean if initially    self.noMaxUseLimit was false then self.advanceDetails always sets maxUseLimit to self.evoucherMaxLimit irrespective of self.noMaxUseLimit which is true now

Comment: You need to add more code.  Like which of your properties are observables and which aren't.  As a rule of thumb anything that is not an observable will not update any of its dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observables only trigger the automatic updates you're looking for when you bind against them in the HTML. What you are looking for is a computed observable.

```
maxUseLimit: ko.computed(function () {
    return self.noMaxUseLimit() ? -1 : self.evoucherMaxLimit;
})
```

A computed observable gives automatic dependency tracking: it determines which other observables (dependencies) influence the value of the computed, and automatically re-runs its logic when one of the dependencies changes.

For more info on computed observables: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html